# parse JSON from URL on Android and display in listview

Tags: android, json

I'm trying to parse a JSON result from a URL in my Android app.
I have tried a few examples on the Internet, but can't get it to work.

What's the simplest way to fetch the URL and parse the JSON data show it in the listview

Json data :

> [{"MemberID":"1","Username":"weerachai","Password":"12345","Name":"Weerachai
>   Nukitram","Tel":"0819876107","Email":"weerachai@gmail.com"},{"MemberID":"2","Username":"adisorn","Password":"ac143","Name":"Adisorn
>   Bunsong","Tel":"021978032","Email":"adisorn@gmail.com"},{"MemberID":"3","Username":"surachai","Password":"gg111","Name":"Surachai
>   Sirisart","Tel":"0876543210","Email":"surachai@gmail.com"}]

Android code :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> MyArrList;
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Permission StrictMode
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        }

        ShowData();

        // btnSearch
        final Button btnSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);
        //btnSearch.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        // Perform action on click
        btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ShowData();
            }
        });
    }

    public void ShowData()
    {
        // listView1
        final ListView lisView1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        // keySearch
        EditText strKeySearch = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtKeySearch);
        // Disbled Keyboard auto focus
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(strKeySearch.getWindowToken(), 0);



        String url = "http:...............php";

        // Paste Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("txtKeyword", strKeySearch.getText().toString()));

        try {
            JSONArray data = new JSONArray(getJSONUrl(url,params));
            MyArrList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            HashMap<String, String> map;

            for(int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++){
                JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);

                map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("MemberID", c.getString("MemberID"));
                map.put("Username", c.getString("Username"));
                map.put("Password", c.getString("Password"));
                map.put("Name", c.getString("Name"));
                map.put("Email", c.getString("Email"));
                map.put("Tel", c.getString("Tel"));
                MyArrList.add(map);

            }

            lisView1.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

            // OnClick Item
            lisView1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> myAdapter, View myView, int position, long mylng) {

                    String sMemberID = MyArrList.get(position).get("MemberID").toString();
                    String sName = MyArrList.get(position).get("Name").toString();
                    String sTel = MyArrList.get(position).get("Tel").toString();

                    Intent newActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this,DetailActivity.class);
                    newActivity.putExtra("MemberID", sMemberID);
                    startActivity(newActivity);

                }
            });

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {

        private Context context;

        public ImageAdapter(Context c)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            context = c;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return MyArrList.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_column, null);
            }

            // ColMemberID
            TextView txtMemberID = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ColMemberID);
            txtMemberID.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
            txtMemberID.setText(MyArrList.get(position).get("MemberID") +".");

            // R.id.ColName
            TextView txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ColName);
            txtName.setPadding(5, 0, 0, 0);
            txtName.setText(MyArrList.get(position).get("Name"));

            // R.id.ColTel
            TextView txtTel = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ColTel);
            txtTel.setPadding(5, 0, 0, 0);
            txtTel.setText(MyArrList.get(position).get("Tel"));
            return convertView;
        }
    }

    public String getJSONUrl(String url,List<NameValuePair> params) {
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        try {
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) { // Download OK
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream content = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    str.append(line);
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("Log", "Failed to download result..");
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return str.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: show us what you tried ?

Comment: best way is retrofit http://themakeinfo.com/2015/04/retrofit-android-tutorial/

Comment: Use this link, you will find it useful.  http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: I have uploaded one example about JSON Parsing in android. I am sure it will help you. Please refer [Viren_Blog](http://virenpurohit.blogspot.in/2016/03/android-json-parsing-example-for.html)

Comment: Thank you for your help.